# DIRECT replacement of UserHostAddress in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

We discovered that `Request.UserHostAddress` is not available in ASP.NET Core (1.0 RC1), as well as `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]`, which returns essentially the same.

Now we found `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` or `HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress` to be the replacement, but is it really a 1:1 replacement for the functionality?

What I mean: `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` only returns the direct IP address of a caller, not a forwarded client address (therefore you have to get `"X-FORWARDED-FOR"`). And that's what we need in our scenario: the direct caller address, not the forwarded one. But we couldn't find any info if `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` in ASP.NET Core is the right choice for us (and if not, what's the alternative?).

Comment: If `Request.UserHostAddress` were available under ASP.NET Core, it would work the same. The problem is that now you have Kestrel.

Answer (score 1):

You only get X-Forwarded-For replacing it when you have plumbed that middleware into the pipeline. So to enable that use `app.UseOverrideHeaders()`.

Without it RemoteIpAddress is going to be 127.0.0.1 in most configurations, because you will have IIS in front of Kestrel.

Comment: Ok, perhaps this helps. Then what's the solution for my initial problem of getting a 1:1 replacement for `Request.UserHostAddress`? It should not return the origin client IP and also not 127.0.0.1, but the IP of the first node outside IIS.

Comment: The solution is to add the middleware. The original feature always showed you the first hop in a connection chain, its just usually that was the client. But if you had a forwarding proxy in front of your web server then it would show that, its just that case was rare. Now its common.

Comment: I don't know if you got me right. I *want* to get the IP of the forwarding proxy, *not* of the client. `UserHostAddress` gave it to me... if I wanted to have the client address, I had to query for XFF.

Now on Core, if I add the middleware and activate `ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor`, then I get the client address, but that's not what I'm interested in my scenario, right?

Comment: Ah. Then don't add the middleware, and you get the address of the forwarding proxy, which is, err, IIS. So it will be localhost (usually)

Comment: Yeah, and that's the shit ;-) Before, with `UserHostAddress` I got the forwarding proxy, now due to Kestrel the IIS. Means, `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` is pretty useless, right?  Seems there is no easy way to realize my scenario (?).

Comment: You want what's in front of IIS, so hop 2? Is that right? (This really isn't clear from the question)

Comment: Yes, that's right. As said: the same behavior as with `UserHostAddress`, so one hop outside the IIS.

Comment: That wasn't exactly the behaviour before, that was a side effect of the hosting model. RC2 will see the ability to nominate which hops you know are internal, so you will be able to configure it to work the way you want.