# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Request ServerVariables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET MVC we have below

```
Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys
Request.ServerVariables.GetValues("REMOTE_ADDR")[0]
Request.ServerVariables.GetValues("HTTP_SCGID")[0]
Request.ServerVariables.GetValues("HTTP_SCMAIL")[0]
```

I am looking for equivalent in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access ServerVariables in AspnetCore 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429604/how-to-access-servervariables-in-aspnetcore-1-0)

Comment: @FaizanRabbani that link didn't help me much.

Comment: This may be of use with regards to REMOTE_ADDR, although the post is a bit old now: [DIRECT replacement of UserHostAddress in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794237/direct-replacement-of-userhostaddress-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 1):

To see headers use

```
          foreach (var item in HttpContext.Request.Headers)
          {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} | {item.Value}");
          }
```

To get value from a single header you can use

```
HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].FirstOrDefault()
```

Remote address:

```
HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()
```

Also Check out

```
HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer
```

If you just type `HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().` see what values VS IntelliSense shows you as available:

[image]